# How can I exit insert mode from a script?

Tags: vimscript

I'm using the answer to this question to create a timeout to insert mode: [Alarm for inactivity](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20375/alarm-for-inactivity)

Once this timeout has been reached, I want the script to make vim leave insert mode, but I'm not sure what I should use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems `stopinsert` worked for me.

The full script would be:

```
" Exit insert mode after 30 secs with no cursor movement

let g:inactivity_limit = 30  " max Insert mode inactivity before fail, in seconds
let g:check_frequency = 1    " seconds between checks

augroup monitor
    au!
    " when vim starts kick off the infinitely repeating calls to the monitor function
    au VimEnter * call timer_start(g:check_frequency * 1000, 'MonitorActivity', {'repeat' : -1})

    " when cursor moves in Insert mode update the last activity time
    au CursorMovedI * let g:last_activity = reltime()
augroup END

func! MonitorActivity(timer_id)
    " when we start we'll initialize the last activity time then return
    " ...gives a little grace period at beginning
    if ! exists('g:last_activity') || empty(g:last_activity)
        let g:last_activity = reltime()
        return
    endif

    " very handy function for our purposes, reltime
    let l:diff = reltime(g:last_activity)[0]

    if l:diff > g:inactivity_limit
        " Not exit insert mode and save buffer
        echom "Exiting insert mode after timeout: " . l:diff
        stopinsert
        let g:last_activity = []
    endif
endfunc
```